Tratando de ejecutar otra ventana de tkinter con reconocimiento de texto con cámara
Estoy realizando un proyecto con una calculadora, más sin embargo, me encuentro con problemas para ejecutar el programa.
Probé ocr2.py individualmente y funciona de maravilla, la cámara se ejecuta y todo bien, simplemente que no puedo ejecutarlo en calculadora.py al hacer click en el botón correspondiente.
Necesito que al hacer click en camera_button se ejecute el script de ocr2.py
Agradezco cualquier aporte <3
Este es el error que me aparece:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\byp3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2068, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\byp3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 862, in callit
    func(*args)
    ~~~~^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\byp3n\OneDrive\Documentos\.UNACH\Teoría matemática de la computación\Calculadora\ocr2.py", line 73, in update_frame
    camera_label.configure(image=imgtk)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\byp3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1822, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\byp3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1812, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tengo el código de calculadora.py:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, StringVar
import tkinter as tk
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc
import math
from ocr2 import camara

load_dotenv() # Cargar variables de entorno

# Tokens
tokens = (
    'NUMBER', 'DECIMAL', 'PI', 'PLUS', 'MINUS', 'MULTIPLY', 'DIVIDE',
    'SIN', 'COS', 'TAN', 'LOG', 'LN', 'EULER', 'EXP', 'SQRT',
    'LPAREN', 'RPAREN', 'EQUALS'
)

# Regex
t_DECIMAL = r'\.'
t_PI = r'π'
t_PLUS = r'\+'
t_MINUS = r'-'
t_MULTIPLY = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE = r'/'
t_SIN = r'sin'
t_COS = r'cos'
t_TAN = r'tan'
t_LOG = r'log'
t_LN = r'ln'
t_EULER = r'e'
t_EXP = r'\^'
t_SQRT = r'√'
t_LPAREN = r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'
t_EQUALS = r'='

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+(\.\d+)?'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

t_ignore  = ' \t'

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()

# Parser
precedence = (
    ('left', 'PLUS', 'MINUS'),
    ('left', 'MULTIPLY', 'DIVIDE'),
    ('right', 'UMINUS'),
    ('right', 'EXP'),
    ('left', 'SIN', 'COS', 'TAN', 'LOG', 'LN', 'SQRT')
)

def p_expression_binop(p):
    '''expression : expression PLUS expression
                  | expression MINUS expression
                  | expression MULTIPLY expression
                  | expression DIVIDE expression'''
    if p[2] == '+':
        p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    elif p[2] == '-':
        p[0] = p[1] - p[3]
    elif p[2] == '*':
        p[0] = p[1] * p[3]
    elif p[2] == '/':
        p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_expression_exp(p):
    'expression : expression EXP expression'
    p[0] = p[1] ** p[3]

def p_expression_uminus(p):
    'expression : MINUS expression %prec UMINUS'
    p[0] = -p[2]

def p_expression_group(p):
    'expression : LPAREN expression RPAREN'
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_expression_number(p):
    'expression : NUMBER'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_pi(p):
    'expression : PI'
    p[0] = 3.14159

def p_expression_euler(p):
    'expression : EULER'
    p[0] = 2.71828

def p_expression_sqrt(p):
    'expression : SQRT expression'
    p[0] = math.sqrt(p[2])

def p_expression_sin(p):
    'expression : SIN expression'
    p[0] = math.sin(p[2])

def p_expression_cos(p):
    'expression : COS expression'
    p[0] = math.cos(p[2])

def p_expression_tan(p):
    'expression : TAN expression'
    p[0] = math.tan(p[2])

def p_expression_log(p):
    'expression : LOG expression'
    p[0] = math.log10(p[2])

def p_expression_ln(p):
    'expression : LN expression'
    p[0] = math.log(p[2])

def p_error(p):
    print("Errro de sintaxis: '%s'" % p.value)
    input_label.config(text="")

parser = yacc.yacc()

# Función para evaluar la expresión
def evaluate_expression():
    expression = input_label.cget("text")
    try:
        result = parser.parse(expression)
        result_label.config(text=str(result))
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error de sintaxis: {e}")

# Función para actualizar el input_label
def update_input_label(value):
    current_text = input_label.cget("text")
    new_text = current_text + value
    input_label.config(text=new_text)

# Función para borrar el input_label
def clear_input_label():
    input_label.config(text="")
    result_label.config(text="0")

def delete_last_character():
    current_text = input_label.cget("text")
    new_text = current_text[:-1]
    input_label.config(text=new_text)



# Interfaz gráfica
app = Tk()
app.title("Calculadora Científica - TECHTITLÁN Team")
app.geometry('525x630')
app.configure(bg='#f5f5f5')
app.resizable(False, False)

# Frame para el input y el resultado
input_frame = Frame(app, bg='#f5f5f5')
input_frame.pack(pady=30)

# Input
input_label = Label(input_frame, text="", width=50, relief='flat', font=('Arial', 14), fg='#252757', bg='#f5f5f5', anchor='e')
input_label.pack(fill='x', pady=(0, 30))

# Resultado
result_label = Label(input_frame, text="0", width=50, font=('Arial', 18, "bold"), fg='#252757', bg='#f5f5f5', anchor='e')
result_label.pack(fill='x')

# Primera fila de botones | sin, cos, tan, log, ln, π, CE, DEL
first_row = Frame(app)
first_row.pack()

button_config = {
    'font': ('Arial', 16,),
    'bg': '#f9faff',
    'fg': '#252757',
    'activebackground': 'lightblue',
    'borderwidth': 0,
    'relief': 'flat',
    'width': 5,
    'height': 2
}

sin_button = Button(first_row, text='sin', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('sin('))
sin_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

cos_button = Button(first_row, text='cos', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('cos('))
cos_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

tan_button = Button(first_row, text='tan', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('tan('))
tan_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

log_button = Button(first_row, text='log', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('log('))
log_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

ln_button = Button(first_row, text='ln', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('ln('))
ln_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

pi_button = Button(first_row, text='π', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('π'))
pi_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

ce_button = Button(first_row, text='CE',
                   font=('Arial', 16),
                   bg='#ff9999',
                   fg='#fff',
                   activebackground='lightblue',
                   borderwidth=0,
                   relief='flat',
                   width=5, command=clear_input_label)
ce_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

del_button = Button(first_row, text='DEL',
                    font = ('Arial', 16),
                    bg='#ff4d4d',
                    fg='#fff',
                    activebackground='lightblue',
                    borderwidth=0,
                    relief='flat',
                    width=5, command=delete_last_character)
del_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

# Segunda fila de botones | M, MR, (, ), ^, /, e, sqrt
second_row = Frame(app)
second_row.pack()

button_config['width'] = 5
button_config['height'] = 3
button_config['bg'] = '#fff'

memory = None

def memorysave():
    global memory
    memory = result_label.cget("text")

def memoryshow():
    if memory is not None:
        update_input_label(memory)

m_button = Button(second_row, text='M', **button_config, command=memorysave)
m_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

mr_button = Button(second_row, text='MR', **button_config, command=memoryshow)
mr_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

left_parenthesis_button = Button(second_row, text='(', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('('))
left_parenthesis_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

right_parenthesis_button = Button(second_row, text=')', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label(')'))
right_parenthesis_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

power_button = Button(second_row, text='^', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('^'))
power_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

division_button = Button(second_row, text='/', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('/'))
division_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

e_button = Button(second_row, text='e', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('e'))
e_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

sqrt_button = Button(second_row, text='√x',
                     font=('Arial', 16),
                     bg='#f9faff',
                     fg='#000',
                     activebackground='lightblue',
                     borderwidth=0,
                     relief='flat',
                     width=5, command=lambda: update_input_label('√('))
sqrt_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

# Tercera fila de botones | 7, 8, 9, x
third_row = Frame(app)
third_row.pack()

button_config['width'] = 11
button_config['font'] = ('Arial', 16, 'bold')

seven_button = Button(third_row, text='7', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('7'))
seven_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

eight_button = Button(third_row, text='8', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('8'))
eight_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

nine_button = Button(third_row, text='9', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('9'))
nine_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

multiplication_button = Button(third_row, text='x',
                               font=('Arial', 16),
                               bg='#f9faff',
                               fg='#000',
                               activebackground='lightblue',
                               borderwidth=0,
                               relief='flat',
                               width=11, command=lambda: update_input_label('*'))
multiplication_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

# Cuarta fila de botones | 4, 5, 6, -
fourth_row = Frame(app)
fourth_row.pack()

four_button = Button(fourth_row, text='4', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('4'))
four_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

five_button = Button(fourth_row, text='5', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('5'))
five_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

six_button = Button(fourth_row, text='6', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('6'))
six_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

subtraction_button = Button(fourth_row, text='-',
                            font=('Arial', 16),
                            bg='#f9faff',
                            fg='#000',
                            activebackground='lightblue',
                            borderwidth=0,
                            relief='flat',
                            width=11, command=lambda: update_input_label('-'))
subtraction_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

# Quinta fila de botones | 1, 2, 3, +
fifth_row = Frame(app)
fifth_row.pack()

one_button = Button(fifth_row, text='1', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('1'))
one_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

two_button = Button(fifth_row, text='2', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('2'))
two_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

three_button = Button(fifth_row, text='3', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('3'))
three_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

addition_button = Button(fifth_row, text='+',
                            font=('Arial', 16),
                            bg='#f9faff',
                            fg='#000',
                            activebackground='lightblue',
                            borderwidth=0,
                            relief='flat',
                            width=11, command=lambda: update_input_label('+'))
addition_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

# Sexta fila de botones | CAM, MIC, 0, ., =
sixth_row = Frame(app)
sixth_row.pack()

button_config['width'] = 7
button_config['font'] = ('Segoe UI Emoji', 16, 'bold')

camera_button = Button(sixth_row, text='', **button_config, command=lambda: [camera_button.config(bg="green"), camara()])
camera_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

micro_button = Button(sixth_row, text='️', **button_config, command=lambda: [micro_button.config(bg="green"), mic()])
micro_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

zero_button = Button(sixth_row, text='0', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('0'))
zero_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

dot_button = Button(sixth_row, text='.', **button_config, command=lambda: update_input_label('.'))
dot_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

equal_button = Button(sixth_row, text='=',
                        font=('Arial', 16),
                        bg='#4cc2ff',
                        fg='#fff',
                        activebackground='lightblue',
                        borderwidth=0,
                        relief='flat',
                        width=11, command=evaluate_expression)
equal_button.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')



# Voz a texto
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

# Comandos de voz
def transformar_comando(texto):
    global comandos
    comandos = {
        "sin": ["sin", "sin de", "seno", "seno de"],
        "cos": ["cos", "cos de", "coseno", "coseno de"],
        "tan": ["tan", "tan de", "tangente", "tangente de"],
        "log": ["log", "logaritmo", "logaritmo de"],
        "ln": ["ln", "logaritmo natural"],
        "pi": ["pi"],
        "(": ["paréntesis izquierdo", "abrir paréntesis", "abre paréntesis"],
        ")": ["paréntesis derecho", "cierra paréntesis", "cerrar paréntesis"],
        "^": ["potencia", "a la", "elevado", "elevado a"],
        "/": ["entre", "dividir", "división", "sobre"],
        "e": ["e", "euler"],
        "sqrt": ["sqrt", "raíz cuadrada", "raíz"],
        "7": ["siete", "número siete", "número 7", "7"],
        "8": ["ocho", "número ocho", "número 8", "8"],
        "9": ["nueve", "número nueve", "número 9", "9"],
        "x": ["por", "multiplicar", "multiplicación", "multiplicado", "multiplicado por"],
        "4": ["cuatro", "número cuatro", "número 4", "4"],
        "5": ["cinco", "número cinco", "número 5", "5"],
        "6": ["seis", "número seis", "número 6", "6"],
        "-": ["menos", "resta", "restar", "resta a", "restar a"],
        "1": ["uno", "número uno", "número 1", "1"],
        "2": ["dos", "número dos", "número 2", "2"],
        "3": ["tres", "número tres", "número 3", "3"],
        "+": ["mas", "suma", "sumar", "sumar a", "suma a"],
        "0": ["cero", "número cero", "número 0", "0"],
        ".": ["punto", "punto decimal"],
    }
    for comando, palabras in comandos.items():
        for palabra in palabras:
            if palabra in texto:
                texto = texto.replace(palabra, comando)
    return texto

# Función para reconocer comandos de voz
def mic():
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.environ.get('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.environ.get('SPEECH_REGION'))
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "es-MX"
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

    print("Escuchando...")
    speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
    texto_reconocido = speech_recognition_result.text.rstrip('.')
    print(texto_reconocido)
    
    comando = transformar_comando(texto_reconocido)

    if "CE" in comando or "limpiar" in comando or "borrar todo" in comando or "borra todo" in comando:
        clear_input_label()
    elif "DEL" in comando or "borra" in comando or "borrar" in comando or "borra uno" in comando or "borrar uno" in comando:
        current_text = input_label.cget("text")
        input_label.config(text=current_text[:-1])
    elif "Resultado" in comando or "resultado" in comando or "igual" in comando or "igual a" in comando:
        evaluate_expression()
    else:
        input_label.config(text=comando)


# Función para capturar una imagen y reconocer el texto


app.mainloop()

Y luego tengo el código de ocr2.py, éste es el que requiero ejecutar dentro de calculadora.py
import cv2
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

subscription_key = os.environ["VISION_KEY"]
endpoint = os.environ["VISION_ENDPOINT"]
computervision_client = ComputerVisionClient(endpoint, CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key))

# Variables globales
capture_flag = False
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def capture_image():
    global capture_flag
    capture_flag = True
def process_frame():
    global capture_flag, cap
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        if capture_flag:
            capture_flag = False
            recognized = ""  # Reiniciar la variable recognized

            # Guardar la imagen temporalmente
            temp_image_path = "temp_image.jpg"
            cv2.imwrite(temp_image_path, frame)

            # Leer la imagen desde el archivo temporal
            with open(temp_image_path, "rb") as image_stream:
                read_response = computervision_client.read_in_stream(image_stream, raw=True)

            # Obtener la ubicación de la operación
            read_operation_location = read_response.headers["Operation-Location"]
            operation_id = read_operation_location.split("/")[-1]

            # Esperar a que el análisis termine
            while True:
                read_result = computervision_client.get_read_result(operation_id)
                if read_result.status.lower() not in ['notstarted', 'running']:
                    break

            # Obtener el texto reconocido
            if read_result.status == 'succeeded':
                for text_result in read_result.analyze_result.read_results:
                    for line in text_result.lines:
                        recognized += line.text + " "

            # Eliminar la imagen temporal
            os.remove(temp_image_path)
            print(recognized)
            return recognized
    return None

def update_frame():
    global cap, camera_label
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        recognized = process_frame()
        if recognized:
            print(recognized)
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        
        # Ensure the image exists before configuring the label
        if imgtk:
            camera_label.configure(image=imgtk)
            camera_label.imgtk = imgtk  # Keep a reference to avoid garbage collection
        else:
            print("Error: Image not loaded correctly.")
        
        camera_label.after(10, update_frame)

def camara():
    """Función para iniciar la interfaz gráfica de la cámara."""
    global cap, camera_label

    # Crear la interfaz gráfica
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Captura de Imagen")

    # Crear el label para mostrar la cámara
    camera_label = Label(root)
    camera_label.pack()

    # Crear el botón de captura
    capture_button = Button(root, text="", font=("Segoe UI Emoji", 24),
                            bg='#4cc2ff',
                            fg='#fff',
                            activebackground='lightblue',
                            borderwidth=0,
                            relief='flat',
                            width=11, command=capture_image)
    capture_button.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    # Iniciar la actualización del frame después de que la interfaz gráfica esté completamente configurada
    root.after(10, update_frame)

    # Iniciar el bucle principal de la interfaz gráfica
    root.mainloop()

    # Liberar la cámara cuando se cierre la ventana
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Esto es todo

Hola Baip, para crear tu ventana secundaria (la que creas en ocr2.py) no uses tkinter.Tk con su propio mainloop como estás haciendo ahora, usa tkinter.Toplevel, instanciandola como  hija de la ventana principal. Cada instancia de tkinter.Tk se ejecuta en un entorno aislado con su propia instancia del intérprete de Tcl y los widgets de una no se pueden usar en la otra (eso incluye a las imágenes). En mi respuesta a la pregunta duplicada lo explico algo mejor. Si tienes dudas comenta. Saludos.
